# Mysql error - you can't specify target table 'tbl_writerremark' for update in FROM clause

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-update

I have this query:

```
UPDATE tbl_writerremark SET status='no' WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM tbl_writerremark WHERE wid=18)
```

and I am getting this error :

```
 "you can't specify target table 'tbl_writerremark' for update in FROM clause"
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this query.

Comment: possible dupliacte of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: Use an `alias` name beside the table name in sub query and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
UPDATE tbl_writerremark SET status='no' WHERE id=(select * from (SELECT max(id) FROM tbl_writerremark WHERE wid=18) as t)
```

Comment: I have use this query but I get this error - "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Thaks for relpy for this, I have use this query and it's working. Query - UPDATE tbl_writerremark SET status='no' WHERE id=(select * from (SELECT max(id) FROM tbl_writerremark WHERE wid=18) as test)

Answer (score 0):

This should work-

```
UPDATE tbl_writerremark SET status='no' WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM (select * from tbl_writerremark) as temp_ WHERE wid=18)
```

In a MySql update and insert, you can't reference the same table which you are modifying in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
This behaviour is documented at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

You will need to stop using the nested subquery and execute the operation in two parts, or alternatively use a simple where clause.

You can use this query, but it's ugly for several reasons, including performance:

```
UPDATE tbl_writerremark SET status='no' WHERE id=(select * from (SELECT max(id) FROM tbl_writerremark WHERE wid=18) as temp_max)
```

Comment: copied the answer from another link.